# How to read a variable outside of the brackets? (or a loop)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Example:
How to get the value of the var idMedico outside of the connection brackets?

```
connection.query("SELECT idmedicos FROM medicos WHERE nome = '" + medico + "'", function (err, result) {
        var idMedico = result[0].idmedicos;
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Not actually. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function query(name, callback) {

    connection.query("SELECT idmedicos FROM medicos WHERE nome = '" + name + "'", function (err, result) {
        var idMedico = result[0].idmedicos;
        callback(idMedico);
    });

}


query('medico', function(result){
    console.log('result : ' + result)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you help :) But it didn't work ;(

Comment: Define "It didn't work". This solution is the way to go. Just pass `result` to another function.